# MySQL add column take long time

Tags: mysql, mariadb, alter-table

I have a multi-tenant based SAAS application with 1200 tenant and i need to run a migrations for all of them. my migration run sucessfuly for all but 3 of them take a long time (i wait 30 minute).

Table for this tenants have not many rows (550, 2500, 3000 rows).

Anyone can help me for finding the problem?

Thank you.

**Hint : I create new table and copy data from original table to new table but now i can't drop or rename original table.**

My Databse: MariaDB-10.3.1

My query was:

```
ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD COLUMN `nationalCode` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Table DDL:

```
    idCustomer           int auto_increment                            primary key,
    CustomerName         varchar(255)                                  not null,
    FirstName            varchar(60)                                   null,
    LastName             varchar(60)                                   null,
    idUser               int                                           null,
    idPayment            int                                           null,
    idCompany            int             default 0                     not null,
    LatitudePoint        decimal(18, 12) default 0.000000000000        null,
    LongitudePoint       decimal(18, 12) default 0.000000000000        null,
    LastOrderDate        datetime        default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' null,
    VisitPeriod          int             default 0                     null,
    LastVisit            datetime        default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' null,
    LastNoOrderDate      datetime        default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' null,
    Credit               decimal(20, 4)  default 0.0000                null,
    RemainCredit         decimal(20, 4)  default 0.0000                null,
    Balance              decimal(20, 4)  default 0.0000                null,
    RFID                 varchar(60)                                   null,
    ReturnCheck          tinyint(1)      default 0                     null,
    AccountStatus        tinyint(1)      default 0                     null,
    FaxNumber            varchar(20)                                   null,
    LiquidationDate      date            default '0000-00-00'          null,
    EldestDue            date            default '0000-00-00'          null,
    MaturityDate         date            default '0000-00-00'          null,
    PriceKind            int                                           null,
    isDefault            tinyint(1)      default 0                     not null,
    TimeStamp            timestamp       default current_timestamp()   not null on update current_timestamp(),
    isDeleted            tinyint(1)      default 0                     not null,
    Address              varchar(255)                                  null,
    PhoneNumber          varchar(60)                                   null,
    MobileNumber         varchar(60)                                   null,
    CustomerErpCode      varchar(60)                                   null,
    StoreType            int                                           null,
    country              varchar(255)                                  null,
    state                varchar(255)                                  null,
    City                 varchar(30)                                   null,
    Region               varchar(30)                                   null,
    idUserCreator        int                                           null,
    idBranche            int                                           null,
    idTagsinfo           int                                           null,
    lastActivityDate     datetime                                      null,
    lastActivityType     tinyint(1)                                    null,
    Status               tinyint(1)      default 1                     not null,
    duplicateOf          int                                           null,
    isConfirmed          tinyint(1)      default 2                     not null,
    createDate           datetime                                      null,
    idProcess            int                                           null,
    idUserConfirmer      int                                           null,
    nextDate             datetime                                      null,
    prevDate             datetime                                      null,
    idImage              int                                           null,
    idColor              int                                           null,
    idRate               int                                           null,
    shop_id              int                                           null,
    shop_id_address      int                                           null,
    LastOrderAgentName   varchar(255)                                  null,
    LastVisitAgentName   varchar(255)                                  null,
    LastNoOrderAgentName varchar(255)                                  null,
    LastImageAgentName   varchar(255)                                  null,
    LastOrderIdAgent     int                                           null,
    LastVisitIdAgent     int                                           null,
    LastNoOrderIdAgent   int                                           null,
    LastImageIdAgent     int                                           null,
    LastImageDate        datetime                                      null,
    idPipeline           varchar(255)    default '0'                   null,
    isSaleActive         tinyint(1)      default 1                     null,
    isReturnActive       tinyint(1)      default 1                     null,
    alley                varchar(256)                                  null,
    street               varchar(256)                                  null,
    plaque               varchar(256)                                  null,
    secondAddress        varchar(255)                                  null,
    description          varchar(255)                                  null,
    appType              varchar(50)     default '-'                   not null,
```

Comment: Try to specify `ALGORITHM = INSTANT` (or, if not applicable, INPLACE). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-column-operations

Comment: I try them (INSTANT not available for my database) but nothing happend

Comment: Is the application in use while you are trying to make this modification?

Comment: Yes but i can have downtime, i try when nobody use this table

Comment: What version of MySQL are we talking about? MySQL supports "instant add column" starting with MySQL 8.0, and MariaDB has this since MariaDB 10.3

Comment: "10.3.1-MariaDB-10.3.1+maria~jessie" but when i run "ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD COLUMN `nationalCode` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL, ALGORITHM = INSTANT;" show "[HY000][1800] Unknown ALGORITHM 'INSTANT'"

Comment: 10.3.1 was an Alpha release https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.3.1/ . 10.3.7 was  the first GA . INSTANT was added to 10.3.7 according to documentation.

Comment: Another reason for upgrading at lest to 10.3.7 -- "Introduce ALTER TABLE attributes ALGORITHM=NOCOPY and ALGORITHM=INSTANT " (from Changelog; over 2 years ago.